# What does the "terms" attribute of the object returned from the posterior method of topicmodels package mean in R?

Tags: r, topic-models

I am using topicmodels in R and I understand how it works when it comes to fitting a topic model to a corpus of documents.

When I take the fitted model and then call the posterior method on it with some new corpus data as input to the same posterior method, it gives back an object containing two attributes viz, topics and terms.

I understand that the topics is the distribution of various topics on the new corpus determined from the model that was fit on the training data.

My question is related to the terms attribute returned by the posterior method. What does that represent? I asked this is because I understand topic models as a methodology where topics generate terms. So I am wondering what do the numbers in the terms attribute mean?

Comment: The help pages for `topicmodels` is rather underwhelming, so it looks like you'll need to track down the links at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model  .  Or this paper directly addressing `topicmodel` :   http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i13/paper

Comment: This is especially ambiguous because `"terms"` attributes are used by the R formula interface for building model matrices, but that doesn't apply here